# increment class onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to know how i can increment class on click my class="item" i want to change on click every time to item1 item2 item3 exc  how can i do this? this is what i want to incrament

```
  <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <textarea  data-bind="value:textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
</div>

<button data-bind="click:addNew">Generate New Div</button>
 <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
      <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">X</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
       <center>
       <span class="text i"  data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: i found this http://jsfiddle.net/YbnGY/7/ which shows an id increment with same class. Not exactly what you were looking for but it could work. Yes, its 2.33 am and I'm still on the computer! I'll go to sleep now... zzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="addNew()">Generate New Div</button>
<div id="my_div" class="item1"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var i = 1;

function addNew() {
    document.getElementById("my_div").classList.remove("item" + i++);
    document.getElementById("my_div").classList.add("item" + i);
}
```

This will increment the class name each time the button is clicked.

Comment: i cant seem to make it work when i try  to click on the button nothing displays no new div or text